# How to check the presence of column in queryset (Django ORM)

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to check if given field is SELECTed in given queryset. Assuming there is `Queryset.has()` method, this should run without `AssertionError`:

```
qs = Author.objects.all()
assert not qs.has('articles_count')
qs = qs.annotate(articles_count=Count('articles'))
assert qs.has('articles_count')
qs = qs.values('pk')
assert not qs.has('articles_count')
```

(assume model `Author` has no field `articles_count` by default)

Answer (score 3):

I am late to the party, but wanted to share my solution if anyone needs it in the future :)

Columns are not present on the QuerySet, but you can check annotated columns on the Query:

```
authors = Author.objects.all().annotate(articles_count=Count('articles'))
assert 'articles_count' in authors.query.annotations
```

Or you could just get one author from QuerySet and check if it has required field:

```
author = Author.objects.annotate(articles_count=Count('articles')).first()
assert hasattr(author, 'articles_count')
```

I would prefer the second method since it's not diving deep into Django's internal system.

If you are planning to use complete QuerySet, but don't want to execute two queries you could evaluate QuerySet and then slice it like so:

```
authors = Author.objects.annotate(articles_count=Count('articles'))
bool(authors) # Just here to evaluate the queryset
assert hasattr(authors[0], 'articles_count') # Doesn't query the database again
```

Comment: The second approach requires to execute an extra query to DB :(

Comment: Yes, but it still may require an unwanted query to DB (e. g. if I want to add more annotations after the check). The first approach would be perfect if `QuerySet.query` was a public API (which [is not](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets) yet in Django 3.2)

Comment: That is was exactly my use case, to add annotation if it doesn't yet exist on the queryset. But as far as I know there is currently no other way (without querying the database) than what I described in first method.
From documentation: **The query attribute is an opaque object. It represents the internals of the query construction and is not part of the public API.**. Exactly this was my concern, and for question asked regarding tests, this is the reason I would use the second method. But for us, I don't think there is another way.. If you find a cleaner way, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and used the try - except logic :

```
try:
    queryset.columnname
except:
    print("Nope, columnname is not in queryset")
```

Hope it helps somebody.
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You can try Python's `hasattr` method:

```
In [3]: hasattr(qs, "articles_count")
Out[3]: False
```

Or if you want to check this attr of every model instance:

```
all([hasattr(x, "articles_count") for x in qs])
```

Comment: `QuerySet` does not gain attributes of the `Model`. Iterating over queryset is not applied for this task because queryset could be very bing

Comment: BTW, you can omit the `[]` and use generator expression (`all(f(x) for x in qs)`) which is more efficient than constructing a list